# SQL table - get count No. of mandatory columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How to get ( Count ) the of  No. of mandatory columns in a table?

Comment: by mandatory, you mean what?

Comment: Do you mean primary key columns? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `NOT NULL`, to do this in SQL Server you could do:

```
SELECT sys.tables.name, c.name
FROM sys.tables
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(sys.tables.name),c.name,'AllowsNull') IS NOT NULL
```

This retrieves all `mandatory` columns for each table in the database.  You could modify this query by specifying just one table.

```
SELECT COUNT(name) FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Client') 
AND COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('Client'),name,'AllowsNull') IS NOT NULL
```

Would `COUNT` the mandatory columns for the `Client` table.

Answer (score 1):

This query can help

I suppose CHARacter_maximum_length>0 is mandatory condition

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'Role' and CHARacter_maximum_length>0
```

For

IS_NULLABLE  is true than IS_NULLABLE = 'Yes'

IS_NULLABLE  is false than IS_NULLABLE = 'No'

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'Role' and IS_NULLABLE = 'Yes'
```